# Read json attribute value from properties file

Tags: java, json

I want to read one of the attributes of json file from properties file.

I tried using `$ref` but no luck. Is this even possible? I have looked this up but could not find any related articles anywhere. Could you please help.

To summarize with an example, inside example.json, I want to fetch the hostName value from application.properties file.So that it can be changed dynamically. Both example.json and application.properties are in the same path.

example.json

```
{
"hostName":{

        "type" : "string",
        "$ref" : "/application.properties/${hostName}"
  }
}
```

application.properties

```
hostName =localhost
```

Comment: Are you using jackson to create the json? Which other technologies are you using? How is this json being built? Are you using springboot?

Comment: Using jackson jsons are created. We are using springboot.

Comment: Can you please add the corresponding code as well? Without looking at the code, I don't think I would be able to suggest anything that proves to be useful, but as far as I can guess right now, I think you need to read the properties file by autowiring the Environment singleton and use env.getProperty(hostName) and set it to your json